# Getting Distance in Inches and Cm from Ultrasonic Sensor in Arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors

I am tinkering with a simple Arduino sketch that detects distances using an ultrasonic sensor. From what I've understood, the trigger sends a ping. The echo listens for an echo that comes back to calculate the distance. This is measured in microseconds.

If that is correct, the question is, how can one determine inches and cm from that ping (that is given in microseconds)? Is this just basic math/physics, and is there just a basic formula for this?

```
void loop() {
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
 delayMicroseconds(2); 
 digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10); 
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

 duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
```

This is the part that I'm having issues with. I want to divide ping time from microseconds to inches and then cm:

```
 distance_in = duration ????;
 distance_cm = duration ????;

 Serial.print(distance_in);
 Serial.print(" in, ");
 Serial.print(distance_cm);
 Serial.print(" cm");
 Serial.println();
 delay(1500);
}
```

Any help, with as much explanation as possible would be appreciated. I'm a newbie to Arduino (and not a heavy-lifter in math)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
distance_cm = ( duration / 29 ) / 2;
distance_in = distance_cm * 0,393701;
```

1 m/s = 100/1000000 = 0.0001 cm/μs

343 m/s = 0.0001 * 343 = 0.0343 cm/μs

0.0343 cm/μs = 1 / 0.0343 = 29.155 μs/cm

Sound travels at 343 meters per second, which means it needs 29.155 microseconds per centimeter. So, we have to **divide the duration by 29 and then by 2**, because the sound has to travel the distance twice. It travels to the object and then back to the sensor.

1 cm = 0,393701 in

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best article I have found on this subject is actually at Arduino.  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Ping

```
/* Ping))) Sensor

   This sketch reads a PING))) ultrasonic rangefinder and returns the
   distance to the closest object in range. To do this, it sends a pulse
   to the sensor to initiate a reading, then listens for a pulse
   to return.  The length of the returning pulse is proportional to
   the distance of the object from the sensor.

   The circuit:
    * +V connection of the PING))) attached to +5V
    * GND connection of the PING))) attached to ground
    * SIG connection of the PING))) attached to digital pin 7

   http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Ping

   created 3 Nov 2008
   by David A. Mellis
   modified 30 Aug 2011
   by Tom Igoe

   This example code is in the public domain.

 */

// this constant won't change.  It's the pin number
// of the sensor's output:
const int pingPin = 7;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // establish variables for duration of the ping,
  // and the distance result in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm;

  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
  // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
  // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  delay(100);
}

long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) {
  // According to Parallax's datasheet for the PING))), there are
  // 73.746 microseconds per inch (i.e. sound travels at 1130 feet per
  // second).  This gives the distance travelled by the ping, outbound
  // and return, so we divide by 2 to get the distance of the obstacle.
  // See: http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/28015-PING-v1.3.pdf
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds) {
  // The speed of sound is 340 m/s or 29 microseconds per centimeter.
  // The ping travels out and back, so to find the distance of the
  // object we take half of the distance travelled.
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```